# how comparable interface return int value, if an interface having only method declaration

Tags: java, interface, comparator

```
String s1="AAA";
String s2="BBB";
int result_int = s1.compareTo(s2);
```

The `result_int` will be negative, which means `.compareTo` method says *s1* is less than *s2*.
My question is: if the `.compareTo` method is from the Comparable interface, then shouldn't an interface method have a body? if the `compareTo` method doesn't have a body, How it will return an integer value when passed two objects?

Comment: You are calling the _String_'s implementation of the interface method _compareTo_. So the actual method body in this case, is in the _String_ class (have a look at the source code of _String_) .

Comment: "if .compareTo method is from Comparable interface" only its declaration comes from Comparable interface, implementation (code) comes from actual type of object (in this case String class). You need to read about polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CompareTo method does have an implementation. The method is implemented in all the classes such as Integer, Double etc. In your case you are using String's compareTo method.

If you want it to be customized as per your class, you do so by overriding the compareTo method.

Comment: Now I understood from Berger, Pshemo and Nikitha's Answer, most of the Wrapper classes in java by-default implement Comparable interface and override .compareTo() method - Thanks for the clarification.